# How to display all elements of an array (composed only of strings) with a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop

I tried to store each element of the array in a variable, and then use a `for loop`. Not to avail.

The array is the following:

```
var WebDevNames = ["CypriotGuy","Kim","Alex","Laura","Arya","David","DutchGirl","Valéry","Juan","Pol"];
```

Comment: Post the code you have tried

Comment: do you have only strings in the array? please add your - not working- code.

Comment: Please show your code, I can't believe you didn't find any information about how to log an array of elements, hence I guess the issue is likely in your code, and it would be interesting to help you from what you've started doing, rather than giving a brand new solution.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the code.
Btw, bear w/ the fact that I just started self-teaching web dev about three weeks ago. I'm also new to StackOverflow.
I'm thus also open to tips and best practices about how to code according to 'world standards'.

Here it is

 var Web_Dev_names = ["CypriotGuy","Kim","Alex","Laura","Arya","David","DutchGirl","Valéry","Juan","Pol"];
var Number_of_names = Web_Dev_names.length;
for (i = 0; i < Numbers_of_names; i++);
  console.log(Web_Dev_names); 
);

I assume this will print the full array every time, and not each name one at a time.

Comment: @LavLav please edit the question and add your existing code, there are mainly three errors to address there: 1) An extra `)` which leads to a syntax error. 2) you're logging the entire array instead of the index. 3) You have an extra `;` after your for loop syntax.

Comment: Sorry for not showing my not-working code. I'm new to both web dev and StackOverflow. I'm learning how to ask great questions.  ;-)
I just edited mine.
@Jack Bashford: Thank you for your solution!

Comment: @briosheje: I did edit my question. Sorry for not putting it out in a great way.

Comment: @LavLav no problem to me, just remember that any reader should be able to easily understand: 1) what is the question. 2) What you're talking about. 3) What is the expcted input and desired output. 4) What you've tried to accomplish. 5) (if any) what is the current output and what doesn't work. Giving these informations helps readers to quickly understand the problem, detect eventual issues and give you the best working solution for your scenario ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `for` loop is the simplest approach - check if the item is a string, and if it is, log it to the console.

```js
var WebDevNames = ["CypriotGuy","Kim","Alex","Laura","Arya","David","DutchGirl","Valéry","Juan","Pol"];
for (let i = 0; i < WebDevNames.length; i++) {
  if (typeof WebDevNames[i] == "string") {
    console.log(WebDevNames[i]);
  }
}
```

If you want to make a new array, you can use `filter`:

```js
var WebDevNames = ["CypriotGuy","Kim","Alex","Laura","Arya","David","DutchGirl","Valéry","Juan","Pol"];
const strings = WebDevNames.filter(e => typeof e == "string");
console.log(strings);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

And then there's the one-line `forEach`:

```js
var WebDevNames = ["CypriotGuy", "Kim", "Alex", "Laura", "Arya", "David", "DutchGirl", "Valéry", "Juan", "Pol"];
WebDevNames.forEach(e => typeof e == "string" ? console.log(e) : e);
```

Or you could `filter` before `forEach`:

```js
var WebDevNames = ["CypriotGuy", "Kim", "Alex", "Laura", "Arya", "David", "DutchGirl", "Valéry", "Juan", "Pol"];
WebDevNames.filter(e => typeof e == "string").forEach(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: because this question is not about gimme the code, but to understand what works or not. but another part is the question itself, which is not clear, if the array contains only strings (which looks like), but the question (which is self explanatory [op]), asks for strings, not elements.

Comment: What do you mean *"but the question asks for strings, not elements."* @NinaScholz?

Comment: the title is "*How to print all string elements of an array with a for loop?*".

Comment: I interpreted that as *"How to print all elements that are strings"*. Can you explain exactly what you mean (really sorry, I just don't understand what you're getting at here).

Comment: Regardless what the title is, the question is simply unclear due to the fact that the input array is a string array already, the OP specified a for loop but didn't show any code. The proper way to help the OP, to me, would be to **fix** his existing code, explaining what's wrong, rather than giving a brand new answer. However, I still think that this one, as an answer, is enough complete and well formatted to deserve an upvote, despite it does not exactly address the real question's problem, since the problem is still unclear.

Comment: Fixing code is usually what I do in these situations @briosheje - unless there's no code, in which case(s) I provide multiple useful/practical solutions.

Comment: btw, you deserve the same comment for you funky onliner: why so complicated with a conditional operator and not using the result of the expression?

Comment: Result of the expression? Do you mean using `&&` like `console.log(typeof e == "string" && e)`?

Comment: @JackBashford don't get me wrong, I would've done the same, I just didn't do that because I thought that this actually wouldn't help the OP understand what he did wrong. Because the question is incomplete, the answer might become incomplete later and the result may be confusing the OP rather than helping him :).

Answer (score 1):

Use `typeof` to get determine if an element is string or not

```js
var WebDevNames = ["CypriotGuy","Kim","Alex","Laura","Arya","David","DutchGirl","Valéry","Juan","Pol"];
WebDevNames.forEach(function(e){
typeof e=="string"?console.log(e):false
})
```

Comment: why so complicated with a conditional operator and not using the result of the expression?

Answer (score 0):

```
var WebDevNames = ["CypriotGuy","Kim","Alex","Laura","Arya","David","DutchGirl","Valéry","Juan","Pol"];

for (var x of WebDevNames) {
 document.write(x + "<br >");
console.log(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have:

```
var Web_Dev_names = ["CypriotGuy","Kim","Alex","Laura","Arya","David","DutchGirl","Valéry","Juan","Pol"];
var Number_of_names = Web_Dev_names.length;
for (i = 0; i < Numbers_of_names; i++);
console.log(Web_Dev_names); );
```

By having a look to

```
for (i = 0; i < Numbers_of_names; i++);
//                                    ^
```

you have a semicolon at the end of the line. This is an [empty statement `;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/Empty) (please have a look to the link) and this means any following code is not looped.

For getting the next statement inside of the loop, remove the semicolon, then the next code is evaluated until the next semicolon or use a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) with

```
for (i = 0; i < Numbers_of_names; i++) {

}
```

You still have not declared `i`. This variable now a global variable, if use in local scope.

Then you have a spelling mistake of

```
for (i = 0; i < Numbers_of_names; i++) {
//                    ^
```

The last line contains an syntax error

```
console.log(Web_Dev_names); );
//                          ^^
```

and an logic error, because you log the whole array instead of an item. You neet to take the index for getting the value.

```
console.log(Web_Dev_names[i]);
//                       ^^^
```

Together with a minor change to the variable names to have lower case letters, because as a convention, only uppercase starting names denotes instanciable variable or functions/classes.

```js
var web_dev_names = ["CypriotGuy", "Kim", "Alex", "Laura", "Arya", "David", "DutchGirl", "Valéry", "Juan", "Pol"],
    number_of_names = web_dev_names.length,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < number_of_names; i++) {
    console.log(web_dev_names[i]);
}
```